# Does cold dry air rich in static electricity cause the Hessdalen lights in Norway?

Tags: electricity, plasma-physics, weather, meteorology

I have read many articles on the Hessdalen lights ( which many professional scientists think are plasmas).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessdalen_lights

I have concluded that cold dry air rich in static electricity causes them by heating air to a plasma state
using electric discharge.
The lights were particularly numerous from 1981 to 1984 during which period there was a long drought in Africa and the west coast of the USA had a terrible drought and the United Kingdom had its warmest weather ever (32 C ). I don't know if Norway was particularly dry in this time period but I am guessing it was.
But even so Norway gets plenty of cold dry air and the lights started in winter December 1981 .Cold air from Norway gave the UK one of its coldest winter temperatures ever (minus 27 C ).

Comment: Cool, dry air is certainly more conducive for things like static discharge, but this would not explain the sudden decrease in the occurrence rate in 2010 (since Norway still gets cold and dry in winter [perhaps not as cold and dry as in the past but still subzero F]).  Given that this is an unexplained phenomenon to the scientific community, I am not sure what type of answers you will receive here.  Regardless, you would need to explain the following.  Why there and nowhere else?  Why the sudden rate change in 2010?  How to generate the broad range of frequencies?

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/53755155. The years 2000 to 2009 were 0.2 C colder than 2010 to 2019.

Comment: It may be important to note that Hessdalen is at 62 degrees latitude and that a Ferrell  weather cell has its boundary with a polar cell at 60 degrees and there is concern that these cells could be changing their boundary positions because of global warming.  The Egyptian pharaoh Thutmose 3rd spoke about similar lights and the pyramids are at 30 degrees latitude which is the boundary of a Hadley weather cell and a Ferrell weather cell.